# Link the logo - HTML- CSS

Tags: html, css

Which is the best way to link the logo to in the following scenario? Shall I replace the DIV with `<a href="img/logo.png">Link</a>` or can i do something in CSS.

The question is can you link the DIV(logo) from the CSS itself

**CSS**

```
.login-container .login-box .login-logo {
    background: url("img/logo.png") top center no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 149px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="login-logo"></div>
```

Comment: Would you like to show the Logo or would you like to set a link to the Logo or both?

Comment: This question is either too broad, **opinion based** or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: @Paulie_D The question is can you link the DIV from the CSS itself

Comment: You mean make a link by CSS...then no. A link is HTML. "Best Way" is asking for opinions....you might want to rephrase the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be best to link your logo `<a href="img/logo.png">Link</a>`

Comment: The question is can you link the DIV from the CSS itself

Comment: No you can't link the DIV from css

Answer (score 1):

Yup, as you mentioned using an anchor tag instead of a div for your logo is the cleanest solution here. You can keep using the same class, then you shouldn't have to revise the CSS much if at all.

```
<a href="#" class="login-logo"></a>
```

Comment: The question is can you link the DIV from the CSS itself

Comment: Nope, you can't actually change the HTML with CSS. If for some reason you really can't change it to a link, you can use a JavaScript click event.

Comment: thanks, I upvoted your answer